# What is a factorial model?

Tags: anova, modeling

In some places they speak of "factorial models".  For instance: [Symbolic Description of Factorial Models for Analysis of Variance](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2346786?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

My question is what is a factorial model? Is it just a model where the explanatory variables are categorical variables?

Comment: Basically, yeah. Here are two references: https://methodology.psu.edu/ra/most/factorial and https://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/factorial.html

Comment: Some useful background material might be gleaned from the WIkipedia page on [factorial experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment), to which factorial models would be applied.

Comment: Does the question include fractional factorials? Do the Wikipedia articles include fractional factorials?

Comment: Interestingly, the factorial experiments article on Wikipedia is classified under "controlled experiments", which seems to indicate it's a very specific kind of experiment design. It doesn't mention "factorial models" though. Am I to assume a factorial model refers only to models used in the context of factorial experiments or is it a broader concept?

Comment: It is certainly a broader concept!